# Using Foreign Key table attributes as an alternative to the FK

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently using `newid()` to generate the unique identifiers for all of my tables. Obviously these are pretty ugly to look at, and hard to understand what data they correlate to, for just about anybody.

For example if I had a table:

```
DesktopMake   DektopType   CPU   DetailsID (foreign key)
```

The `DetailsID` is currently this long 16 digit mash up of hard to look at numbers, however the other attributes in the `Details` table, such as:

```
PurchaseDate   CurrentOwner   Price
```

These are much more relevant than the horrible 16 digit number, is there a process in which I could (on said MVC application), show the other 3 attributes, perhaps when the user hovers over the `DetailsID`? To make it easier for the user to know what they're really looking at?

Thank you in advance, I'm sure this is possible (best not speak to soon), but I can't for the life of me find the right words to search the correct thing! Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

View containing the 'example' table:

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DesktopMake)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Accessory.MonitorType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Component.CPU)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Detail.DetailsID)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DesktopMake)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Accessory.MonitorType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Component.CPU)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Detail.DetailsID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.DesktopID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.DesktopID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.DesktopID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: How does your view looks like ?

Comment: You can show that information in a tooltip. Did you try that ?

Comment: Added in the view, sorry I'd forgotten to add it! A tooltip would work, but they're messy and I was hoping for a more repeatable solution? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you should engineer your solution to never even try to display PK/FK values in your "end-user" interface.

System generated PK/FK values are important for the database, but not for people.  "Natural" keys are good for humans to look at, and are used for LOGIC in the database, but not as database keys, per se.

As far as what you decide to use for the PK/FK system-generated values, there is a lot of debate over different schemes using newid() GUID's versus simple auto-increment integer values, but regardless of your preference, they generally don't make much sense to users, so it's usually better just to commit to never using them for human interaction.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, suppose it would reduce the need for workarounds etc if these fields just weren't shown and an alternate more user friendly attribute was available, advice taken, thanks for the insight. :)